# how to build a JFrame window with a graphic area paintComponent with JTextField, JButton and JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, paintcomponent

I've been searching in google how to build something that looks like in the image. Text boxes, labels, buttons with actions and a graphic area all in one JFrame, but I only can find them separated. I mean, I understand how to build them separated but no how to put them together.
I've been reading about using GridBagConstraints but is very confusing.
I would appreciate any tip.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: *but no how to put them together.* - use a panel to logically group components. In your case you might have one panel for the components on the top. A JPanel uses a FlowLayout, so you will see then all in one line. The top panel is added to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START and the graph panel to the BorderLayout.CENTER of the frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples. *but is very confusing* - is not a question. What part of the demo code in the tutorial do you not understand.

Comment: The center JPanel is a drawing JPanel.  See the Oracle tutorial [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) to see a working example of building a drawing JPanel.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) and include your panels ("separated components") at the regions (north, south, east, west, or center) you want.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JPanel actions = new JPanel();
    JPanel graph = new JPanel();

    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(actions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(graph, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: The default layout for a JFrame is the BorderLayout.